Acceso denegado desde Windows 11
Tengo una aplicación que accede a unas carpetas de otro ordenador para imprimir reports. Estaba funcionando correctamente, pero de repente, a la hora de acceder a la carpeta Reports devuelve un Acceso denegado desde la aplicación.
En principio esto ocurre desde la aplicación de la KB5044033, una actualización de NET framework.
He revisado los permisos y parecen correctos. Desde el explorador accedo a la carpeta sin problema y desde una virtual con Windows 7 y desde código fuente el comportamiento es el deseado. No tengo manera de reproducir el error desde el código fuente para poder ver el punto exacto o si hay algún mensaje más concreto desde desarrollo.
Había pensado en desinstalar la KB, pero no me ofrece dicha opción el Historial de actualizaciones.
¿Alguna sugerencia sobre qué o dónde podría mirar para intentar solventar esto?
Saludos.

Para entender, tu dices que ejecutas la aplicación desde el IDE y funciona, pero si lo ejecutas desde el .exe no??? y con ejecutarlo desde el .exe me refiero a hacerlo manualmente, doble click en el ejecutable

Efectivamente. Y la diferencia de que el IDE está en una virtual con Windows 7 y el ejecutable en Windows 11. Pero atacan a la misma carpeta los dos.

Si.. pero desde difernetes versiones de .net!!!! pq win 7 ya no tiene actualizaciones... puede ser eso???

Sí, claro, diferentes versiones seguro que son. Lo que no entiendo es que pese a darle todos los permisos habidos y por haber, tomar el control de la carpeta por el usuario, etc., siga sin poder acceder a ella desde ese código.
